# OutOfRangeError logged at each epoch after upgrade from Tensorflow 1.8.0 to 1.11.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, upgrade

I have a TfRecordsDataset:

```
...
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset_iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
(...) = dataset_iterator.get_next()
```

And then the standard:

```
test_session.run(dataset_iterator.initializer)
while not done:
    try:
        ... = test_session.run([...])
        batch_count += 1
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        done = True
```

This worked perfectly with Tensorflow 1.8.0. Today I upgraded Tensorflow to TF 11.1.0, and I now have an error:
 `OutOfRangeError: End of sequence [[{{node dataset/IteratorGetNext}} = IteratorGetNext`

at each end of an epoch. The error itself is actually caught, but the error is printed on the console. Can someone point out what is actually happening ?

Comment: if you get a solution, please update here, I am facing exact same issue.

Comment: well, I think this is related to this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12414) which points to this 
 [commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2c97ee31b0cb584b255232d46d4e42db4cbcb1c2). It seems to happen only within unit tests framework. I just mute the logging with `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.FATAL)` if needed.  I haven't seen the spurious log in production though, so I live with it for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved in TF 1.12.0.